# How to change Angular renderer value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to implement background color change when I click `th` element. Issue is when I click it works fine but I need to implement if I click another `th` element it will be turned off for previous one. It will not be turned off if I click same `th`, in short until I change to another `th`.
Angular 8 my directive looks like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[sortColumn]'
})
export class SortDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() data: any;
  @Input('sortKey') key: any;
  @Input('sortNumber') num: number;
  private toggleSort: boolean = false;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
      let parentNode = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode;
      let children = parentNode.children;

      if (this.data && this.key) {
        let sortedData: any = this.sortArray();
      }

      if (this.data && this.num) {
        let sortedData: any = this.sortNums()
      }     
      this.changeTextColor()
    })
  }

  changeTextColor() {
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement,"background-color","green");
    this.toggleSort = !this.toggleSort;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using a service...

Register all directives to a service to manage the directives state (`isActive`).

This is a simplified example using a button Directive, but the same principles apply to your example:

**The manager service**:

```
  managedDirectives: BtnDirective[] = [];

  addManagedDirective(btn: BtnDirective) {
    this.managedDirectives.push(btn);
  }

  removeManagedDirective(btn: BtnDirective) {
    this.managedDirectives.filter(item => item !== btn);
  }

  activate(btn: BtnDirective) {
    this.managedDirectives.map(item => {
      if(item === btn) {
        item.isActive = true;
      } else {
        item.isActive = false;
      }
    })
  }
```

**The directive**:

```
  @HostBinding('class.is-active')
  isActive: boolean;

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.managerService.activate(this);
  }

  constructor(
    private managerService: ManagerService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.managerService.addManagedDirective(this);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.managerService.removeManagedDirective(this);
  }
```

Full working example can be found here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1gk9ya

The service solution works independently of the DOM structure. No need for querying DOM elements. You use Angular and not jQuery ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the style of the recently clicked element, you could assign it a class. This way, when you click on an element, you could validate that no other element has this particular class, and if so remove it.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[sortColumn]'
})
export class SortDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() data: any;
  @Input('sortKey') key: any;
  @Input('sortNumber') num: number;
  private toggleSort: boolean = false;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
      let parentNode = this.el.nativeElement.parentNode;
      let children = parentNode.children;

      if (this.data && this.key) {
        let sortedData: any = this.sortArray();
      }

      if (this.data && this.num) {
        let sortedData: any = this.sortNums()
      }     
      this.changeTextColor()
    })
  }

  changeTextColor() {
    let currentlyActiveElement = document.querySelector('.active');
    // there is currently and active class, we remove it.
    if(currentlyActiveElement) {
        currentlyActiveElement.classList.toggle('active');
    }


    this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement,"active");
    this.toggleSort = !this.toggleSort;
  }
}
```

And then in your CSS :

```
.active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: it works for once, and after that I got exception `Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined`

Comment: My bad, remove the `[0]` part.

Comment: Works like charm, you saved my day!!

Comment: this is a very very non-angular approach. would not recommend. other answer is better

Comment: @bryan60 that's fair. Maybe it will help someone not looking for an angular related question.